# How to source AWS credentials profile from .aws/credentials for aws cli

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I have the following programmatic access credentials for AWS in my `.aws/credentials` file.

how to specify which credentials to use for AWS cli commands? and verify which credentials are being used?

[image]

Comment: `AWS_PROFILE=amplify aws sts get-caller-identity`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To verify:

```
AWS_PROFILE=amplify aws sts get-caller-identity

# OR

aws sts get-caller-identity --profile amplify
```

The same to run commands:

```
AWS_PROFILE=default aws eks --region .......

# OR

aws eks --region ....... --profile default
```